# Speech Recognition Python

Tags: python, module, speech-recognition

I keep getting: NameError: name 'statement' is not defined. It's because i'm not saying anything, and I tried to do an "except" to catch the errors and print something but it still does the error. Here is the code:

```
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say Anything: ")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            statement = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
            print("You said : {}".format(statement))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print(random.choice(command_errors))
        except NameError:
            print(random.choice(command_errors))
        if ai_name in statement:
            engine.say("At your service")
            response_to_wake = ("At your service, " + user_pronoun.lower())
            engine.runAndWait()
            print(response_to_wake)
            Wake = True
        else:
            Wake = False
```

Comment: you could as start create `statement = None` to have this variable all time. And later you can use `if statement is not None:` to recognize if `recognize_google` could recognize speech. OR you should create `statement = ''` inside `except` to create this varaible when `recognize_google` will raise error.

Answer (score 1):

If `recognize_google` throws, then `statement` will not be defined after the try-except block. Consider moving the `if ai_name in statement` block inside the `try` block or initialize `statement` before it.